# Triggers or views on frequently updating table

Tags: optimization, stored-procedures, trigger, view

We have a table which is frequently updating. We have a scheduler to update this table which runs every 10 minutes. There are not more than 50k records in this table but when scheduler runs, database server consumes almost 100%. So now we are thinking to apply triggers on all tables that are used in this scheduler (which runs a SP to update that table) or should we make a simple view? Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: *table which is frequently updating.* How frequently? for example, 1000 updates, average 10 rows each... *We have a scheduler to update this table which runs every 10 minutes.* In addition to frequent updates? *now we are thinking to apply triggers on all tables* In addition to separate updates and updates from scheduler?

Comment: @Akina - Scheduler runs every 10 minutes. Scheduler updates the table. 'In addition to separate updates and updates from scheduler' - Yes

Comment: You type "a table which is frequently updating". Each 10 minutes - this is NOT "frequently".

Answer (score 0):

> ... not more than 50k records ... database server consumes almost 100%

Heavy CPU load suggests (to me) that there's lots of stuff happening in memory, which suggests poorly performing queries doing a lot of table scanning.

Look in the Slow Query log to see which queries are taking along time to run and look to tune them.

Comment: We are inserting all records in table using select query which is having 13 joins and 60 columns. So is it good to apply triggers on all those tables to keep updating the table (so that we get rid of scheduler) or we should just make a view?